# Dealing with Strings in Cython

Tags: string, cython

I'm trying to just do the most basic string operations with Cython but can't even seem to get started without having to do a bunch of weird stuff.

I just would like to know how to do something like:

```
def f(str s):
   cdef int i
   cdef char c
   for i in range(len(s)):
      c = s[i]
      ...
```

This, unfortunately, won't even run due to a type error.  If I check what the type of s[0] is, for example, it says it's a string...

(To clarify here, the method f is being called from Python.)

So I can get it work by adding this weird conversion step, but I just want to access the data, and I want it to be fast (that's why I'm using Cython after all), surely there's a better way?

```
def f(str py_s):
   s = (<unicode>py_s).encode('utf8')
   cdef int i
   cdef char c
   for i in range(len(s)):
      c = s[i]
      ...
```

If I now put the line print(c) in place of the ellipsis above, the method prints out the characters as integers rather than characters.  Why?  How can I change this?

Comment: This looks like the relevant cython string paragraph: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#single-bytes-and-characters, `"the char type coerces to a Python integer value by default, so that the following prints 65 and not A"`.

Comment: Nice find, thanks.  I guess I won't worry about the encoding for now... It says it's supposed to be fast.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?